# The template specified for component AppSection is not a string

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, webpack, angular8

I am using Angular 8 , Webpack with .Net Core 2.

```js
    const path = require('path'); -- Path
    const rxPaths = require('rxjs/_esm5/path-mapping');

    const webpack = require('webpack');

    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
    const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
    const FilterWarningsPlugin = require('webpack-filter-warnings-plugin');

    const helpers = require('./webpack.helpers');

    const ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');


-- Development process start
    console.log('@@@@@@@@@ USING DEVELOPMENT @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');

    module.exports = {
        mode: 'development',
        devtool: 'source-map',
        performance:{hints: false},
        entry: {
            //polyfills: './ClientApp/polyfills.ts',
            //vendor: './wwwroot/vendor.js',
            app: './ClientApp/app.ts'
        },
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: /node_modules/
        },
        output: {
            path: ROOT + '/wwwroot/',
            filename: 'dist/[name].bundle.js',
            chunkFilename: 'dist/[id].chunk.js',
            publicPath: '/'
        },

        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html'],
            //alias: rxPaths()
        },

        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true,
            contentBase: path.join(ROOT, '/wwwroot/'),
            watchOptions: {
                aggregateTimeout: 300,
                poll: 1000
            },
            hot: true
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    use: [
                        //'ts-loader',
                        'awesome-typescript-loader',
                        'angular-router-loader',
                        'angular2-template-loader',
                        'source-map-loader',
                        'tslint-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name]-[hash:6].[ext]'
                },
                {
                    test: /favicon.ico$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader?name=/[name].[ext]'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    loader: 'raw-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.svg$/,
                    loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: "[name].[ext]",
                        outputPath: 'wwwroot/assets/svgs/',
                        publicPath: 'ClientApp/'
                    }
                }
            ],
            exprContextCritical: false
        },
        plugins: [
            function () {
                this.plugin('watch-run', function (watching, callback) {
                    console.log(
                        '\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m',
                        `Begin compile at ${new Date().toTimeString()}`
                    );
                    callback();
                });
            },

            new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),

            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
            }),

            // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: ['vendor', 'polyfills'] }),

            new CleanWebpackPlugin({
                cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ['./wwwroot/dist', './wwwroot/assets'],
                root: ROOT
            }),

            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                filename: 'index.html',
                inject: 'body',
                template: 'ClientApp/index.html'
            }),

            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: './ClientApp/assets/*.*', to: 'assets/', flatten: true }
            ])

            //new FilterWarningsPlugin({
            //    exclude: /System.import/
            //})
        ]
    };
    
    // Package.Json
    {
  "author": "Sandeep Kumar",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.1",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^8.0.3",
    "@types/flatpickr": "^3.1.2",
    "alertify": "^0.3.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^7.5.4",
    "angular4-notify": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.3.0",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "notie": "^4.3.1",
    "omni-slider": "^1.2.1",
    "pell": "^1.0.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "description": "sms app",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.9",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "raw-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.4",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
    "url-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.34.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-filter-warnings-plugin": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "wwwroot/index.html",
  "name": "client-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ngc": "ngc -p ./tsconfig.json",
    "start": "concurrently \"webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --port 44380\" \"dotnet run\" ",
    "webpack-dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && webpack",
    "webpack-production": "set NODE_ENV=production && webpack",
    "build-dev": "npm run webpack-dev",
    "build-production": "npm run ngc && npm run webpack-production",
    "watch-webpack-dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && webpack --watch --color",
    "watch-webpack-production": "npm run build-production --watch --color",
    "publish-for-iis": "npm run build-production && dotnet publish -c Release"
  },
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "-vs-binding": {
    "ProjectOpened": [
      "watch-webpack-dev"
    ]
  }
}
```

When i run my .net core 2 application, it successfully redirecting to index.cshtml. But, i am getting an error - The template specified for component AppSection is not a string

I have tried many ways to make it run, but no success.

Comment: My .net core app is having a ClientApp folder for angular project and tsconfig, tslint and package.json file is at the root of .net core app

Comment: App Section TSimport { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { SafeUrl } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: "AppSection",
    templateUrl: "appSection.component.html"
})
export class AppSection implements OnInit {
  @Input() public Banner: SafeUrl;
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.Banner = '';
  }
}